# ffmpeg mxf file setdar to 16/9 but keep audio and video same without encoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, codec

I have numerous 50Mbps IMX50 wrapped MXF videos.  Media info/media tab read the aspect ratio as 4:3.  I'd like to change that to 16:9.  Ideally I would not re-encode all the content because I have 1000s of hours of content to apply this to.  Ideally ffmpeg would just perform the data modification to switch the aspect ratio to 16:9.

I used the command below and it changed the aspect ratio but it then made my bit video rate 200Kbps and removed 3 of my 4 audio tracks but left the audio bit rate untouched.  The video and audio codec remained the same.  I'd like the bit rate and number of audio tracks to remain untouched; again without re-encoding if possible.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mxf -vf setdar=16:9 output.mxf
```

I also found that I can't use the -vcodec copy and -acodec copy with the filters (-vf).

Is there a way to use the *setdar* parameter and retain the original audio and video codec settings?

Comment: This information is not part of the actual encoded frames, but bitstream data (which codec, btw?)  that could theoretically be changed without re-encoding the footage. But I'm not aware of any tool that can do that.

Comment: @slhck - for H.264 streams, see https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=152419

Answer (score 0):

No. At best you can try

```
ffmpeg -i input.mxf -map 0 -c copy -aspect 16:9 output.mxf
```

However, `setdar` is a filter and so, if used, the video will have to be re-encoded.

Comment: Thanks Mulvya.  That's what I was afraid of.  I had tried what you suggested before but it didn't work.  I'll keep searching for another option.  Re-encoding would take months.  Thank you.